# Random forest in R - other error measures in OOB sample

Tags: r, random-forest

I am preparing a predictive model using `randomForest` package in R. However I would like the function to report the other than accurace OOB error measure. In fact I want to use Gini coefficient (some name it Powerstat). I know how to calculate Gini, but the proglem is in implementing the error measure.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how the out-of-bag error rate is comparable to Gini coefficient. Do you want to change the criterion used for constructing the forest or the measure used to report the performance of the fitted forest?

Comment: By my question I meant the reporting o performance.

Comment: I hate to say it but your description of the problem is very brief making it hard to tell what you are after. Do you want to extract the OOB predictions to allow you to calculate Gini instead of error rate? How exactly do you calculate Gini btw? What information do you need to do it?

Comment: Yes, the description may be quite general. Sorry for that. To answer your questions, it would be enough to extract OOB predictions (as probability) with the indices of OOB observations. I calculate Gini with rcorr.cens from Hmisc package,

Comment: When looking at the `rcorr.cens` documentation I guess you are working on some survival analysis problem, but the `randomForest` package can only do regular classification. So there are obviously additional details missing in the question. Working out things like this as I go along take an unnecessary long time, so please provide *all* details necessary to solve the problem and some example data when asking questions on SO.

Comment: I do not mean to be rude in any way, but I suggest you read the excellent [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) blog post and improve your question.

Comment: @Backlin, no I am not working on survival analysis. Function rcorr.cens was designed for survival analysis, but can be used in different situations (see e.g. http://www.rcreditscoring.com/gini-coefficient-in-r/). Anyway you are right, I will improve my question tomorrow.